# Field size recommendation?

Tags: database-design

Is there any place where I can find recommendation about the length of the fields that I should set in a database?

I just started fixing some bugs in a project that almost all of its fields are set to 50...

first name, last name, email...

I think in this case, first name and last name could be less than 50...

anyway, doesn't hurt to ask =)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "as large as possible".

Most database fields are actually variable size, so it doesn't matter what random number you pick.

Therefore, pick the largest random number you can get away with.

I go with 255 unless there's a compelling reason not to.

One compelling reasons for shorter is the overall row size is too huge.

The other compelling reason is an actual defined standard for maximum length.

Comment: That's my approach, too.  Last I read (which is admittedly some time ago) for most databases, a varchar uses only as much space as you store in it plus one byte for the length.  In fact, I think some databases just let you specify varchar with no length specifier.  So I use lengths for those kinds of fields only if I want to LIMIT the length to something shorter than 255 or whatever the max is.

Comment: SQLite doesn't actually use the sizes for anything.  They're just used for compatibility with databases where size mattered.

Comment: Completely disagree. Why not make them varchar(max)? If you allow a user to stuff a copy of *War and Peace* into a column, they will. You are begging for crappy data.

Comment: @Thomas: No one said anything about a user interface, did they?  Where was that mentioned?

Comment: Remember that you want to be able to read the data also. The size of a row that you fetch is limited by the buffer in the database driver, so you may want to limit the sizes so that a record can't get too large to fetch.

Comment: @Guffa: The overall row size is also limited by physical page sizes and some other considerations.  But I just make the physical page sizes as large as possible, also.  Storage plummets in price.  One can spend more time optimizing a gigabytes of storage than those few gigabytes are worth.  I had to break up a meeting where 4 DBA's quibbled over megabytes.  Megabytes!  Their time was more expensive than the disk space they were optimizing!

Comment: @S.Lott - The db should be designed to protect itself against bad data outside of the application. Applications change far more often than databases. What happens when you have multiple applications hitting the same database? What happens when a DBA comes along and pushes a bunch of data from another system? You cannot rely solely on an application outside the db to protect the quality of the data.

Comment: @Thomas: Large != Crappy. Data quality has nothing to do with random size limitations.

Comment: @S.Lott- The core issue is correctness of the data. If you allow a column to store 8000 characters for an email address, someone will stuff something other than email address into it. Many data elements **have** a specification and therefore it is not random. Email addresses, VINs, bank codes, currency codes etc. all have very specific makeups including size constraints. The best way to ensure you get the most correct data is adher to those constraints.

Comment: @Thomas: In rare cases, there are sizes.  However, the question was a general one.  In the rare case when there is a defined limit, then that's a possible constraint.  In general, there are no constraints and no reason to impose one.

Comment: @S.Lott - Size limitations absolutely can have an affect on data quality in that many data elements have specific or realistic size limits. If you allow for more storage than is specified for a data element such as email address, you are opening another vector by which bad data to get into the database.

Comment: @S.Lott - Certainly, there are many types of data which have specific size limitations. US Postal Addresses, various ISO codes, VINs, tax identification numbers etc. Some elements do not, but one can take a reasonable guess. Is it reasonable to assume we might find a person with an actual first name longer than 25? What about 50? I bet not. I would rather error on the side of data correctness and update the schema should we find such a person with such a long name than the other way around and that has nothing to do with performance, speed or size (although those can be a factor too).

Comment: @S.Lott Large **can** equal crappy if the size allowed is larger than the specification of the data being stored. If you allow more than 8000 for a VIN, someone will eventually put crap into that column.

Comment: @Thomas: "someone will eventually put crap into that column" Why?  We're not talking about the UI are we?

Comment: @S.Lott - You cannot assume people will only access the data through one particular UI. Databases can get integrated through mergers and with outside sources. UIs get replaced far more often than databases and new interfaces might come online that allow write access to the data outside of the original app. The database should be designed with protections that increase the odds of rejecting bad data regardless of the UI.

Comment: @Thomas: All true.  However, you **must** assume the UI's work.  You cannot built all the business rules into the database.  Since you **must** trust the UI's, please trust the UI to prevent crap data.  It's trivial to find common business rules which cannot be implemented as database constraints, sizes, or anything else. That's why we have "application" software. Since business rules exist -- and can't be trivializes as DB constraints -- we **must** trust the UI to prevent crap data.  Minimizing each column isn't *essential*.

Comment: @S.Lott  - The db should be designed to *increase the odds* that it rejects bad data. Yes, there are going to be some business rules which must be implemented outside the db but that doesn't mean all or even most rules. The db should not trust the UI (or have very little trust) because "the" UI could easily become many UIs or become a different UI. The UI should not be the **only** system protecting against bad data. It isn't *essential* to use `datetime` for date values but it makes life *a lot* easier. Columns should tailored to the data they are storing including size.

Comment: @S.Lott - In an ideal world, there would be a data type for every type of data that had a specification. I.e., instead of choosing "varchar" for an email address, you would have a data type called "EmailAddress". For a currency, you would have a data type called "ISO639-3" etc. However, this is obviously not practical as the variety of data elements is too vast. That doesn't mean we cannot get close using data types, Check constraints and column sizes.

Comment: @Thomas:  If you can't trust the UI, **and** you can't encode all the business rules in the database, what do you do?  You do the best you can.  And fussing over sizes of every single field is not the **best** you can.  It's generally a waste of time.

Comment: @S.Lott - You cannot **ONLY** trust the UI and you should give it as little trust as you can. It is only a waste to someone that has never had to clean up a db filled with crap because the UI overlooked a restriction (or a new UI was built and overlooked it) or someone bypassed the UI and inserted a bunch of crap directly into the db. The job of the entire system, UI, middle-tier and db, is to ensure the data is as correct as possible and no tier should trust the tier above it (or give as little trust as possible).

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not going to change my answer.  You've raise one important point.  If there's a standard, apply it.  Your blanket statement about not trusting the UI is something I cannot comprehend.  Please stop repeating it.  Since the UI cannot be trusted and the DB cannot be complete, I see no reason for fussing and fine-tuning.  Large != crappy.  All your examples of faulty UI have nothing to do with large and everything to do with ordinary UI bugs.  I am a DBA.  I have cleaned up bad databases.  My answer stands.  Size is not a cause of crap in the database.

Comment: @S.Lott - Then why not use varchar for date values? Why use data types of any kind beyond varchar/nvarchar? Why not use varchar(max) for everything? Size is not the *cause* of crap. Arbitrarily large sizes *allow* crap to get in that wouldn't otherwise. Making a column varchar(8000) does not mean that the column will automatically contain crap. However, it does allow for it. UIs come and go and multiply far more often than the db. It makes no sense to argue that because the db cannot implement every possible business rule that none should be implemented in it.

Comment: @Thomas: I did not at any time suggest avoiding strongly-typed columns.  I'm not sure why you're suggesting using varchar for dates.  Was it in the answer somewhere?  I'll take it out.  "Arbitrarily large sizes allow crap to get in that wouldn't otherwise" is unsupported by facts or any of your examples.  Can you please stop repeating it?

Comment: @S.Lott - Arbitrarily large sizes absolutely enable entry of crap that would not get in otherwise. How can you possibly argue otherwise? Example, `currency varchar(8000)` vs `currency char(3)`. I can stuff in values into the former column that are not currencies nor could possibly ever be valid currencies. It is axiomatic that if you allow for storage beyond that the size of valid data for a data value, baring other database constraints, you make it **POSSIBLE** for storing bad data.

Comment: @S.Lott - You seem to have this override faith in the UI/middle-tier of any given system. On many occasions, I have seen oversights and mistakes in the UI and/or middle-tier that were only caught by the database. The database is the last line of defense against bad data. UIs and middle-tiers get bypassed frequently. We'll have to agree to disagree. IMO, it is better to take the conservative approach with column sizes in the interest of correctness. That doesn't mean being stingy, but it also doesn't mean throwing caution to the wind and making everything varchar(255).

Comment: @Thomas: Time spent sizing the columns is time wasted.  A small or large DB column has no effect on a UI failure.  They're independent.  A small column of crap is just as useless as a large column of crap.  Why waste time researching the median name size plus 2 standard deviations?

Comment: @S.Lott - Btw, you do not do your report designers any favors with fat columns. They have assume if a col is 255 characters, that it might actually have or will have that much data. - For the same reason that time spent choosing data types and adding foreign key and check constraints is important, time spent ensuring that columns are sized to store the values that are appropriate is important. Both exercises are meant to ensure correct data.

Comment: @S.Lott - Btw, a UI failure isn't the only source failure. People bypass UI's and stuff data directly into databases all the time.

Comment: @Thomas: Time spent sizing the columns is time wasted. If they bypass the UI, they can create a small column of crap or large column of crap.  Right?  Size didn't stop them from creating crap, did it?  It only forces them to create a small load of crap instead of a large load of crap.  But it's still crap data, correct?  I'm missing the value of keeping size small when there are so many ways to create crap data.

Comment: @S.Lott - I could replace in your statement with any activity which adds data integrity. "Time spent adding foreign keys is time wasted". "Time spent choosing data types is time wasted." It only feels like wasted time in the beginning with no data. If you try to push data from another system that is larger than the column allows, most dbs will throw an error (In fact the spec calls for throwing an error).

Comment: @Thomas: "replace in your statement with any activity which adds data integrity".  I don't see how.  Your examples are all much more important that field size limits.

Answer (score 1):

If the column in question is used to store something that contains a specification, like email address, then use that specification. For example, the maximum allowable length for an email address is 256 characters. Anything prior to the `@` sign can be no longer than 64 characters. Other examples of codes that have known specifications are bank codes, currency codes, language codes, VINs, ISBNs etc. You should use the length most appropriate to the value. The objective is to have the database protect itself against bad data as much as possible by matching the specification of the column to the specifications of the data.

Names, however, are trickier. The very concept of a first name and last name is not universal. In addition, the length of first and last names varies quite a bit between government agencies.  My inclination with first and last name is to start with 25 characters and see if that will suffice (25 character first or last name is a seriously long name). However, be aware you may run into trouble with international names. Thus, it also best to create a general "Name" column where users can enter the person's full name.

In terms of a site that contains all of these specifications, there is no such place as far as I'm aware. Google is your best choice or the authoritative source (e.g. IRS for tax identifiers, DMV for driver's license specs, USPS for address specs etc.)

[RFC3696](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696)

Comment: is on the right track by suggesting you follow the specification for the data width.  In your case I would expect the specification is how many characters will fit on the data entry form.  If the form only accepts 32 characters there is not really any reason to make it varchar(max).  When using a char field SQL may be able to use inplace updates to the data instead of moving data off page resulting in extra IO.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use 32 for things like first name/last name. I have a friend with a hefty surname which convinced me to allow for input that long..

Answer (score 0):

25 is usually a safe-bet. If you need to modify in the future this is possible with just a few lines of code...